# WebView with HTML5 and input types

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to load a local HTML5 file that includes a `<input type="email" name="email">` nad  `<input type="date" name="bday">` into WebView but these input type appear as a regular `textbox`.

From what i found, HTML5 in WebView supported from SDK version 14 or 15, anyhow my project is targeted to SDK version 16 and greater. Also I checked (by http://html5test.com/) if my WebView supports those input types and the results are that `email` is supported and `date` is only partially supported.

Is there anyway to make these HTML5 input types available in my App?